# How are we able to send 512 bit hash as a bytes32 variable?

Tags: solidity, web3js, keccak, sha3, data-types

I have a code that is working:

### solidity

```java
function checkSignature(bytes32 h, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure returns (address signer) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";    
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix,h));  
    signer = ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s); 
}
```

### javascript

```js
    const message = "Hello";
    const h = web3.utils.soliditySha3(message);
    console.log(h.length);
    let signature = await web3.eth.sign(h, second);

    var r = signature.slice(0, 66);
    var s = "0x" + signature.slice(66, 130);
    var v = "0x" + signature.slice(130, 132);
    v = web3.utils.toDecimal(v);
    v = v + 27;

    const result = await multisig.checkSignature(h, v, r, s);
    //result === second
```

The logged length of `h` is 66. 512bit hash should be 64bytes. The first 2 bytes(0x)denotes this is a hex value.

I am sending it as a solidity bytes32 variable which has a fixed length of 32. How is the code working?

I might be missing something very obvious. Please point it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `soliditySha3`,  which produces a `256-bit` (`32 bytes`) hash, because of that your code works with `bytes32`.

As you can see in the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3), the output of `soliditySha3` is something like the following, with a length of `66`, `64` without `0x`. Check that one byte corresponds to two chars, so the result is `32 bytes`.

```
var x = web3.utils.soliditySha3('234'); // auto detects: uint256
> "0x61c831beab28d67d1bb40b5ae1a11e2757fa842f031a2d0bc94a7867bc5d26c2
```

Comment: Ok. I forgot a hex char was half a byte. There are 16 combinations which can be represented by 4 bits.